# When we concat two observable Duplicate items will be eliminated in output stream?

Tags: java, rx-java, observable, concatenation

In RxJava When we concat two observables, will it eliminate duplicates items in the list.

Example :

```
Obeseravble.concat(Observable.just(localDataItemList),Observable.just(remoteDataItemList))
.observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
.subcribeOn(AndroidScheulers.mainThread())
.subcribe(new Subscriber<List<Item>>(){
    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {
    }
    @Override 
    public void onError(Throwable e) { 
    } 
    @Override 
    public void onNext(List<Item> concatinatedItemList) { 
        //this will have any duplicated items in case
        //if one item happend to be in the both list before 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it will not filter duplicates. Please have a look at the first test.

It shows that duplicates are put through the pipe.

The second test filters the duplicates with `distinct` operator. But be careful with `distinct`, because it could lead to memory leaks with very long lasting Observables.

```
@Test
public void duplicates() throws Exception {
    Observable<Integer> just = Observable.just(1, 2, 3);
    Observable<Integer> just1 = Observable.just(2, 3, 4);

    Observable.concat(just, just1).test()
            .assertResult(1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4);
}

@Test // Filters duplicates
public void duplicatesFilter() throws Exception {
    Observable<Integer> just = Observable.just(1, 2, 3);
    Observable<Integer> just1 = Observable.just(2, 3, 4);

    Observable.concat(just, just1)
            .distinct()
            .test()
            .assertResult(1, 2, 3, 4);
}
```

Comment: can you help with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61352701/passing-list-to-rxjava-concat-and-when-remove-item-in-onnext-or-onerror-causes-c?noredirect=1#comment108536141_61352701 
Thanks